# jquery how to change color of non selected tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

i have a page with various jquery widgets. Among them there is a tab widget and i need to change the color of the non-selected tabs only.

tried this css:

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    background: rgb(143, 167, 52);
}
```

the problem is that this css changes the color of other jquery widgets.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add qualifiers to your selectors, either using the `ui-tabs` class (as below) or the id of your specific tabs widget.

```
.ui-tabs .ui-state-default, .ui-tabs .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-tabs .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    background: rgb(143, 167, 52);
}
```